# Incrementing in an IF Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, increment, do-while

In the code below, why will it not work if I place an if statement telling it to increment if 
"root <101;". I have been starring at this and cannot figure out why it doesnt like that. 
Is this just due to scoping?

```
do {
    ++root;
    if ((number / root) == root) {
        System.out.printf("\nThe square root of %.0f is %.0f.\n", number, root);
        root = 101;
    } else if (root == 101) {
        System.out.printf(
                "The number %.0f does not have a square root.\n", number);
    }
} while (root < 101);
```

such as this:

```
do {
    if ((number / root) == root) {
        System.out.printf("\nThe square root of %.0f is %.0f.\n", number, root);
        root = 101;
    } else if (root < 101) {
        ++root;
    } else {
        System.out.printf(
                "The number %.0f does not have a square root.\n", number);
    }
} while (root < 101);
```

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting, and what are you actually observing?

Comment: first of all, pleas not that `System.out` doesn't have a `printf`method. Change it to `println`.

Comment: @rciovati:  Yes, there *is* a `System.out.printf` method.  what are you talking about?

Comment: System.out.printf for java is valid, I use it all the time for class. I have them all set to double, i am using double because with integer it will auto round.

Comment: Oh, I should not trust of my memory and double check javadoc next time, Sorry.

Comment: When i use the code at the bottom, if a number is given to the system via Scanner that does NOT have a square root, it will skip all the code and end the program.

Comment: Try and use `Double.compare()` instead of equality?

Comment: Ill check. The code at the top does exactly what i want it to do, i just am stumped as to why the bottom code wont work. Scoping was the only thing i could think of

Answer (score 0):

So generally that's the expected behavior - your middle if statement reaches the exit condition of the loop. Basically, the last if is never executed, because the root is never greater than or equal to 101.

Try this code:

```
do {
    if ((number / root) == root) {
        System.out.printf("\nThe square root of %.0f is %.0f.\n",number, root);
        break;
    }
} while (++root < 101);

if( root == 101) {
    System.out.printf("The number %.0f does not have a square root.\n", number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This boolean expression worries me:

```
(number / root) == root
```

Here's why.

- If neither `number` nor `root` are `double`, then you have integer division.  Depending on what you're going for, this may be undesirable.
- If either `number` or `root` *are* `double`, then you have the chance of some floating-point inaccuracies - sometimes, a floating point quotient won't *exactly* be equal to a whole number.

  That brings up another scenario:

  - If `root` is a double, then you *may* run into issues when doing `++root`.  It's a bit worrisome when trying to increment a floating-point value.

With all of that out of the way, we're kind of left with guessing at straws as to the real types of these variables.  But, let's assume for the sake of argument, that `number` is a `double`, and `root` is an `int`.  Depending on what you want to do, you may want to change your equality to an inequality to check if it's less than or equal to, or you may want to rework your comparison altogether.

Comment: they are all double. When i used int it will auto round and make it think the square root of 50 is 7.

Comment: That's going to be problematic for the equivalence check then.  I would encourage you to check to see if `root` *really* needs to be a `double`, too.

Comment: it does not need to be. The issue though was not that the math wasnt correct, it was that if i input a value via scanner that did not have square root, it will instantly end the program instead of the else statement triggering. The top code works properly, the bottom part of the code was an older version of it that i was trying that would not work right. I just dont understand why root will not increment within the else if statement. Scoping?

Answer (score 0):

Your code complicates a very simple function you are trying to implement. Your use of a do-while loop compounded with a nested if structure is causing me (and certainly you) more headache than needed. Without seeing your full code, it's hard to understand what's going wrong.

The first thing I notice (in your second code block) is that you have the potential for an infinite loop. Consider the case where root is a number greater than or equal to 101. Your code will simply default to the final else statement and infinitely print:

```
 The number ___ does not have a square root.
```

Now, if I understand your code correctly, you are trying to calculate the square root of a number up to some maximum root number of 100. Here is a better implementation of the code:

```
 public void printSquareRoot(int number, int max_root) {
     int root = 1; // note it's important to start at 1 
     while ( root <= max_root ) {
         if ( (number / root) == root) {
             System.out.printf("\nThe square root of %.0f is %.0f.\n",number, root);
             return; // we can quit out of the function
         }
         root++; // here we are incrementing to the next root
     }

     // Notice that if we reach this line of code then 
     // no root was found for the number
     System.out.printf("The number %.0f does not have a square root.\n", number);
 }
```

Within your code, I would call this function with the **number** you wish to calculate a square root on and **max_root** the max number of roots you wish to try. For example, if you want to calculate the square root of 25 up to a maximum number of roots of a 100:

```
printSquareRoot(25, 100);
```

Comment: yea i had double root =1; The top part of the code i had works fine. My question was why does the program just end with the second piece of coding i showed you all if the program is given a number hat does not have a square root via scanner?? Root = 1 so it should increment to 100 then stop and display the message stating their is no square root if the first if statement isnt true.